# Error Emulator Windows Phone 8 on Xamarin Forms: Impossible to connect the virtual machine

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have an error on Hyper-V virtual machine with Windows Phone emulator. When I try to deploy my Xamarin.Forms project, the error displayed is:

> Impossible to connect the virtual machine if the problem persist
>   contact administrator

I reinstalled Hyper-V many times, I uninstalled Team Viewer, I stopped the firewall and Windows Defender but the problem persists. My OS is 64-bit Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: The Windows 8 installation isn't a virtual machine itself? What is the exact error message? Does is have any error code?

Comment: there is no error code and the installation isn't a virtual machine. When i deploy th project on visual studio 2015 there is another error: it tell me that the connection is lost by another application